# Python, Install Beautiful Soup4-4.1.3 on Mac. Access Denied?

Tags: python, macos, beautifulsoup

I can't figure out how to install BeautifulSoup4 on Python.
I've downloaded it, unpacked it and moved it to User directory.
Typed in Terminal 'cd beautifulsoup4-4.1.3' to enter directory
Then I type 'python setup.py install'
Then I get this message:

```
    Adams-iMac:beautifulsoup4-4.1.3 adamparis$ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
creating build/lib/bs4
copying bs4/__init__.py -> build/lib/bs4
copying bs4/dammit.py -> build/lib/bs4
copying bs4/element.py -> build/lib/bs4
copying bs4/testing.py -> build/lib/bs4
creating build/lib/bs4/builder
copying bs4/builder/__init__.py -> build/lib/bs4/builder
copying bs4/builder/_html5lib.py -> build/lib/bs4/builder
copying bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py -> build/lib/bs4/builder
copying bs4/builder/_lxml.py -> build/lib/bs4/builder
creating build/lib/bs4/tests
copying bs4/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib/bs4/tests
copying bs4/tests/test_builder_registry.py -> build/lib/bs4/tests
copying bs4/tests/test_docs.py -> build/lib/bs4/tests
copying bs4/tests/test_html5lib.py -> build/lib/bs4/tests
copying bs4/tests/test_htmlparser.py -> build/lib/bs4/tests
copying bs4/tests/test_lxml.py -> build/lib/bs4/tests
copying bs4/tests/test_soup.py -> build/lib/bs4/tests
copying bs4/tests/test_tree.py -> build/lib/bs4/tests
running install_lib
creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4': Permission denied
Adams-iMac:beautifulsoup4-4.1.3 adamparis$
```

At the end it says 'Permission denied. Why is this?

Comment: sudo? are you logged as root?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did use Sudo and it worked. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try $ sudo python setup.py install. type in your password when prompted.

Answer (score 2):

you can type `sudo pip install beautifulsoup4`

Answer (score 1):

It’s trying to install into the system directory `/Library/Python`, but only the root user can do that. You could use `sudo` to become root, but—

If you just want to install the package for yourself, try `python setup.py install --user` to install into your home directory under `/Users/yourname/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages`. It’s automatically in your Python path, you won’t need root access, and in the extremely remote event that there is malware in the Python package you downloaded, it will corrupt only your account instead of the entire computer.

[`pip`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) also has a `--user` option for installing directly from [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), as do some versions of `easy_install`, but not all of them… Python packaging can be messy sometimes.

Comment: I worked first from the 1st answer and that worked. Thanks for your reply.